# Why Are These Animations Not Opposites?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to play an animation in reverse by using jQuery. The original animation (which works perfectly) is as follows:

```
    function initialSuccess(){
    $('#box3').animate({
                left: '-50%'
                    }, 300, function() {
            $('#box3').css('left', '150%');
             });

            $('#box3').next().animate({
                left: '50%'
            }, 300);

};
function initialError(){
    $('.step3-tag').html("Whoops, Something Went Wrong");
    $('.loader').replaceWith("<img src='images/error.png' id='error-img'>");
    $('#box3').append("<button class='step3-retry-button' id='retryBtn'>Try Again</button>")
$('#retryBtn').click(function() {


    $('#box3').empty();

    $('#box3').animate({
                left: '150%'
                    }, 300, function() {
            $('#box3').css('left', '150%');
             });

            $('#box3').prev().animate({
                left: '50%'
            }, 300);
             $('#box3').append("<h3 class='step3-tag'>Let Us Check That For You, One Sec!</h3> <div class='loader'></div>")
}

);
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I've also tried leaving the numbers the same, but changing the direction from `left` to `right`, but that also did not work.

**Added Information**
This is the JsFiddle example, I am trying to reverse the animation (go from div 3 to div 2 if the user presses a button)

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/

**Added Information**

```
    function initialSuccess(){
    $('#box3').animate({
                left: '-50%'
                    }, 300, function() {
            $('#box3').css('left', '150%');
             });

            $('#box3').next().animate({
                left: '50%'
            }, 300);

};
function initialError(){
    $('.step3-tag').html("Whoops, Something Went Wrong");
    $('.loader').replaceWith("<img src='images/error.png' id='error-img'>");
    $('#box3').append("<button class='step3-retry-button' id='retryBtn'>Try Again</button>")
$('#retryBtn').click(function() {


    $('#box3').animate({
                left: '-50%'
                    }, 300, function() {
            $('#box3').css('left', '-50%');
             });

            $('#box3').next().animate({
                left: '-50%'
            }, 300);

});
}
```

`initialSuccess()` is the result then al goes well, and causes the div to slide off the screen to the left ad be replaced with the next div in live. `initialFailure()` happens when another operation fails, and is supposed to act as a "Back" button of sorts. `initialFailure()`'s animation is the one that is failing/ pushing the divs in the same (wrong) direction regardless of the changes in the animation itself.

Comment: @ChrisHappy Check updates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you need is following set of animations:

```js
$('.box').click(function () {
    $('.box').each(function () {
        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '50%',
            }, 500);
        } else if ($(this).offset().left > $('#container').width()) {
            $(this).css("left", "-150%");
        } else {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '150%',
            }, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

You can see a full example with 2 sets of animations at http://jsfiddle.net/af88ukfx/1/

**Update**

I'm still not sure what is your exact layout and what exactly should happen but as I wild guess I think that you need something like this:

```
function initialError2() {
    $('.step3-tag').html("Whoops, Something Went Wrong");
    $('.loader').replaceWith("<img src='images/error.png' id='error-img'>");
    $('#box3').append("<button class='step3-retry-button' id='retryBtn'>Try Again</button>")
    $('#retryBtn').click(function () {
        $('#box3').animate({
            left: '150%'
        }, 300);

        $('#box3').prev().animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 300);
    });
}
```

Comment: It is working in JsFiddle, but not working in my program

Comment: @Ethan, it is really hard to guess what's wrong by such a short description. Could you provide more details on what you actually do in your program and what beahvior you see when it is "not working"?

Comment: of course, sorry about that. Essentially the same this is happening. I changed the code, reloaded the page, cleared the cache, and retried it, but the result was the `box` moving off to the left still,  instead of the right...

Comment: @Ethan, well that's sounds unbelievable. Can you put a breakpoint inside `each` and see which if-branch is applied to which box? And also check afterwards that DOM matches that? You might have other click listener still attached. To check for the latter, Chrome has a very useful feature "Break on ..." > "Attribute modification" available at the DOM Element inspector in the right-click context menu. So enable such a breakpoint on one of boxes and ensure that attributes are modified only once per click and by the code you expect to do that.

Comment: Check edits to question, it should show you how I am implementing these animations.

Comment: @Ethan, you layout is still not clear for me. At the start what is visible? And what is `$('#box3').next()`? And what should be shown after `initialFailure` animation? Should it be `$('#box3').prev()`?

Comment: if `$('#box3').prev()` is a legitimate option then I believe this has been my problem the entire time. After `initialFailure()` `box2` is supposed to replace `box3` with the inverse animation as before.

Comment: @Ethan, so does my last code with `prev` fix your issue? If no, let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139546/discussion-between-serggr-and-ethan).

Comment: It fixed the problem, although the div's still move to the right, it is replaced by the correct one.

Comment: @Ethan, have you tried the code I suggested or just replaced `next` with `prev` in your code? To move box3 to the right its `left` should be animated to `150%` rather than `-50%`

Comment: Although the correct box is now replacing the old one, the it is still not sliding off in the right direction.

Comment: Check updated code, was going to settle with `box3` moving off to the right and `box2` coming in the from the left, even though both are supposed to be moving right.

Comment: @Ethan, I'm not sure I understand your problem. It looks like I put code quite close to what you already have at https://jsfiddle.net/6jjdsafy/2/ and to me both "success" and "error" buttons seem to work as you want. Could you point what's wrong with that fiddle?

Comment: When an error happens (to relate to to your fiddle) Div3 slides off the screen to the right, but div2 comes in from right to left. They overlap each other half way. Div2 is supposed to come in left to right

Comment: @Ethan, it obviously doesn't happen in my example. Or did I miss something? So the obvious place to see is starting position of the `Div2`. Is it initially at `left=-50%` is in my example or at `left=150%`? And if latter, why it is there? It looks like your like `$('#box3').css('left', '150%');` is the source of the issue and my sample doesn't have it. I expect you have the same line in your code for `Div2` for some strange reason.

Comment: Initially `Box2` is at `left=-50%`. This is when `box1` is displayed. After `box1` is done, `box2` slides in from `left=-50%` to the middle of the screen, then proceeds to follow `box1` to the left when `box3` appears. If `box3` fails, then it must slide back to the right (the direction it came from) and `box2` must come back from the left to the center of the screen.

Comment: @Ethan, let's continue this in a [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139546/discussion-between-serggr-and-ethan)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139712/discussion-between-ethan-and-serggr).

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the above function in `$(document).ready()`

Please find the fiddle link .
https://jsfiddle.net/q7jud6yq/

Comment: how do you explain about this said by the OP: ***The original animation (which works perfectly)...***? So if this answer was correct, the OP should have not been able to run the original code ***so that*** he knew that it worked perfectly? Anyway it's strange that the second snippet does not work for him (while it should work flawlessly). The OP must have something wrong in his environment, but this answer just provides ***one possibility***. You would be a good mind guesser/reader. But answering is not for such kind of person. The right region/section for mind readers is the comment section.